Algebraic Topology CW complexes
I am a new PhD candidate and struggling with algebraic topology.
In Hatcher, there is this question: Show that there are only countably many homotopy types of finite CW complexes.
I guess it requires homology to prove, but I am not sure how to do so.

Take a look at Theorem 2C.5 in Hatcher, this should help you answer your question :)

Please add what you have tried to solve the problem. This site is not for solving your homework.

Thank you for hint @jasnee !

Thank you for telling me how this cite works! @MartinBrandenburg
